# How to convert Excel Form to OpenXData

Tags: xml, excel

I have a form in excel sheet and I want it to be online in an OpenXData server. I have tried redesigning the forms all over again in openxdata and it the forms does not look very good.

Is there a way I can import an excel sheet form to openxdata form so that it can be fill-able online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to import an excel spreadsheet into OpenXData, but since OpenXData XML is based on the Xforms standard, perhaps you could try the following:

1. Convert your Excel document to XForms - using [XLSForms](https://opendatakit.org/use/xlsform/) from ODK for example
2. Create a new Study/Form on the OpenXData server
3. Copy and Paste the Xforms XML code into the "Xforms Source" tab in the OpenXData Forms Designer
4. Click the "Open" button on the toolbar (it's the first one on the left which looks like a magnifying glass over a folder)

Hopefully, your XForm will be loaded and you will see a tree load in the "Forms" pane on the left with the hierarchy of your form.

I tested with a basic form, and this worked.